# Can the angle 2π/5 be trisected using ruler and compasses?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm trying to figure out how to do this problem. I know that it can be trisected using ruler and compasses based on the theorem that

> For a positive integer N, an angle of measure ​$\frac{2\pi}{N}$ is
>   trisectible if and only if 3 does not divide N

but I tried to understand why that was true and couldn't, so I didn't want to use this theorem since I couldn't find/do/understand a proof of it.

I've tried to see if $f(t) = 4t^3 - 3t + cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\frac{2\pi}{5}))$ as I know this would imply that it is constructible (and I have been able to show this), but wasn't sure how to tell if $f$ was reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\frac{2\pi}{5}))$

So I was looking for some assistance on how to either prove the statement in yellow or how to show $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\frac{2\pi}{5}))$

Thank you!

Comment: It might help to note that $\frac{2\pi}{15}=\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{5}$.

Comment: @Wojowu thank you! i got it from this

Comment: Your theorem appears to be wrong. If implies that if $N=7$ then $2\pi/7$ is trisectible so that we can construct an angle of $2\pi/21$. This is not possible. The theorem should say that if $N$ is divisible by $3$ then we can't trisect an angle of measure $2\pi/N$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh hmm ok, thank you! I read it on the wikipedia page about angle trisection so that's why I didn't want to use it anyway unless I could find/understand a proof of it

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The theorem is correct as stated and is a standard exercise in Galois theory. Perhaps you're confused by the fact that $\frac{2\pi}{21}$ is not a constructible angle, but we aren't looking to construct it from scratch, rather we're allowed to use an angle of measure $\frac{2\pi}{7}.$ In terms of Galois theory, we wish to find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3n}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)]<3.$

Comment: If $3|n$ then $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3n}):\mathbb{Q}]=3\varphi(n)$ while $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n}):\mathbb{Q}]=\varphi(n),$ so the extension is degree 3 and hence $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ isn't trisectable. If on the other hand $3\nmid n$ then the degrees are $2\varphi(n)$ and $\varphi(n)$ respectively, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3n}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)]=2$ and $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ is trisectable.

Comment: Thanks @Zerkoff for the details. And yes I interpreted the theorem in terms of construction of angle of $2\pi/(3N)$ rather than assuming that angle of $2\pi/N$ is given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the equilateral triangle and the pentagon can be constructed with straightedge and compass, and $\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{4\pi}{15}$ can be bisected:
[image]

In algebraic terms, the minimal polynomial of $\cos\frac{2\pi}{15}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $1+8 x-16 x^2-8 x^3+16 x^4$ and 
$$ \cos\frac{2\pi}{15} = \frac{1}{8} \left(1+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6 \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to construct $e^{2\pi i/15}$, which is a solution of $x^8 - x^7 + x^5 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1=0$.

Observe that this polynomial is symmetric $x^8P(1/x)=P(x)$. Therefore We can write it as $x^4Q(x+1/x)$ with $Q$ a polynomial of degree $4$.

$$\begin{align}Q(x)&=x^4-x^3-4x^2+4x+1\\&=-1/4 (-2 x^2 + (1 + \sqrt{5}) x - \sqrt{5} + 3) (2 x^2 + (\sqrt{5} - 1) x - \sqrt{5} - 3)\end{align}$$

A polynomial of degree $4$ that can be solved in quadratic radicals, and therefore so can the original one.

Comment: Solved in radical, yes. Solved using a straightedge and a compass, not necessarily

Comment: @Wojowu I know. I am still typing.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(2\pi/15)$ is contained in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{15})$ where $\zeta_{15}=\exp(2\pi i/15)$. We have $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{15}):\Bbb Q]=\phi(15)=8$, so $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{15})/\Bbb Q$ Galois extension with a $2$-group as a Galois group. For an element to be constructible over a field, it is sufficient that is contained in a Galois extension with a $2$-group as s Galois group. Thus $\cos(2\pi/15)$ and $\zeta_{15}$ are constructible even over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: More generally one can construct an angle of measure $2\pi/N$ if and only if $\phi(N) $ is a power of $2$ and by number theory this means that $N$ should be product of distinct Fermat primes and some power of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Call $$\phi=cos({2\pi\over5})$$

One root of $f$ is $T={1+\sqrt{5}\over4}$ which is somewhat conjugate to $\phi={-1+\sqrt{5}\over4 }$. By forming the product you find $T\phi={4\over 16}=\frac14$.

Therefore you expect $f$ to factor as $$f(t)=(t-\frac {1}{4\phi})(\text{some quadratic expression})$$

From there it is not hard to see that the quotient is itself with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\phi)$.

Answer (score -1):

[GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/CukhmEVy)

straightedge slip on the point B  - line i

divider  FIG , slides on straightedge , after slipping point F straighte line BC , point  G describes lokus1

section lokus1 and line k point J , when changing the angle, the point J must be manually set to the intersection

construction of regular polygon is possible by means of the proportion of the angle